# image tearing when whatching movies

Tags: drivers, video, tearing

I replaced my pc (fx 8320, gtx 760) with a laptop lenovo z-51 (i3, m360) I have image tearing problems in video players like smplayer, kodi,vlc and also my graphics is detected as intel not as amd 360m. How can I solve these problems?

I use ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 1):

I might be late, but for future visitors it might be helpful:

Although I have Intel graphics, this did the trick for me.
Install CompizConfig Settings Manager (available in the Software Center). Open it and click on the OpenGL button, under the "General" section. Then untick "Sync to VBlank".

Hope it helps!